# FragmentTransaction.replace replaces only first Fragment in a container

Tags: android, replace, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have two fragments in a single container (say A and B) added in a single transaction. I try to replace them with C.
According to the documentation, replace should remove all fragments from a specified container and then add new one. Instead, it replaces only first one. So I end up with B and C fragments. 
This confuses me a lot. Is it a bug or what?

I already know that adding several fragments to single container is considered bad practice. But I'm curious anyway.

UPDATE:
found that before : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28452

Comment: did you ever got the answer to that?

Comment: No, I just live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do like this:

```
Fragment fragmentA = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentC));
     Fragment fragmentB = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentB));
     FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

         ft.remove(fragmentA);
            ft.remove(fragmentB);
            ft.commit();
```

And then just add new fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragmentC).commit();
```

Comment: I believe this will work, but the question is why documentation wrong.